# How to chain multiple Axios calls together so that they run synchronously and each call can use the data returned by the previous call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have an array of items and I need to do an Axios post for each item in the array. Each item depends on data returned from the previous item so I need them to execute synchronously. The problem I'm facing is I don't know how many items are going to be in the array. If I knew the array count I could do the following:

```
let my_array = [34, 44, 72];

axios.post(
    'url-to-get-data',
    {
        post_data_1: my_array[0]
    }
    ).then(res => {
        axios.post(
            'url-to-get-data',
            {
                post_data_1: my_array[1],
                post_data_2: res.data
            }
            ).then(res => {
                 //Third axios post.....
            }
            ).catch();
        }
        ).catch();
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Recursion is your friend here. I've done this with a function inside of a loop that either returned a resolved promise or a recursive call to itself. If you can know where you are in the iteration, you can test for if you are the final element. If you are the final element, you resolve the original promise. If you are not the final iteration, you should be able to recall yourself with the next piece of the iteration (and resolve function) and continue until you are. Does this make sense? I can totally elaborate if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially asking how to chain (an unknown length of) async work.

Using promises (and recursion):

```js
let asyncDec = count => Promise.resolve(count - 1);

let handler = count => {
  console.log('handled', count);
  if (count)
    return asyncDec(count).then(handler)
};

asyncDec(10).then(handler);
```

Using await/async:

```js
let asyncDec = async count => count - 1;

let main = async () => {
  let count = 10;
  while (count >= 0) {
    console.log('handled', count)
    count = await asyncDec(count);
  }
};
main();
```

Comment: I implemented the first method and it worked. Thanks so much!!